# Getting Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory even after adding wlfullclient.jar

Tags: java, gradle, weblogic, oracle-ucm

wlfullclient.jar generated and pushed to local Maven and imported in project as

```
compile group: 'com.weblogic',  name: 'wlfullclient', version : '10.3.6'
```

When I try to run that project in local runnable java its working fine. After creating runnable jar and deployed in server I got  ***Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory***
error. Tried importing jar from local dir also getting same error.
Jar file was available in generated jar lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please at weblogic.jar Package, on the Weblogic 10.3.6 server, the package path is in the bea / Weblogic / lib directory weblogic.jar In this bag